# Equation of plane parallel to $x$-axis.

Tags: vectors

Problem in several editions of Larsen calculus texts:

Plane passes through $(1,-2,-1) $ and $(2,5,6)$ and is parallel to $x$- axis.

Solution given takes cross-product of vector between the points and vector $u = i$, claiming both lie in plane. How could unit vector $ (1,0,0) $ lie in plane parallel to $x$-axis?

Thank you.

Comment: It has to do with translation invariance of vectors. The vectors have the same properties at any position in space, so a vector travelling "along" the axis is always parallel to it, even if it is placed somewhere else in space.

Answer (score 0):

By definition,the  vector $i$ is parallel to all planes parallel to $ XY$ and $XZ$ planes, or any other plane rotated about x-axis and translated arbitrarily thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

Well just think, point $(1,0,0)$ lies on the $x$-axis, not on $y$ or $z$-axis. Hence your vector is parallel to $x$-axis and therefore lies in an arbitrary plane parallel to $x$-axis. 3D is just the working of your brain :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are confusing an *Orientated Segment* with a *Vector*.

An orientated segment (sometimes called *applied vector* in physics) is defined by the ordered couple of two points (A,B), which are the ends of the segment, and in which the direction from $A$ to $B$ is chosen.

A vector $\mathbf v$, i.e. an ordered D-uple, can be thought as individuating the "class" of all the orientated segments such that
$$
{\bf v} = \mathop {OB}\limits^ \to   - \mathop {OA}\limits^ \to  
$$
which can be otherwise written as
$$
\mathop {OB}\limits^ \to   = \mathop {OA}\limits^ \to   + {\bf v}
$$
(vector $\bf v$ "applied" in $A$).

Thus:
 - the or. segment $((0,0,0),(1,0,0))$ lies on the $x$ axis but **does not lie** on a plane parallel (and distant) from it;
 - the vector $(1,0,0)$ **is parallel** to the $x$ axis and to any a plane parallel from it.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=(1,-2,-1)$ and $B=(2,5,6)$.

The vectors $\overrightarrow{UV}$ where $U=A$ or $B$ and $V=U+(1,0,0)$ will lie in a plane that is parallel to the $x-$axis.

The line through $A$ and $B$ can be expresses as

$$L(t)= A + t(B-A)=(1,-2,-1) + t(1,7,7)$$

Note $L_{A,B}(0)=A$ and $L_{A,B}(1)=B$.

The $x-$axis can be thought of as the line through the points $(0,0,0)$ and $(1,0,0)$.

$$L_x(s)=s(1,0,0)$$

The "direction" of $L_{A,B}$ is $B-A = (1,7,7)$ and the "direction" of the $x-$axis is $(1,0,0)$.

So the cross-product $(1,7,7) \times (1,0,0)=(0,7,-7)=7(0,1,-1)$ will be perpendicular to both lines.

The plane we seek must therefore be perpendicular to $(0,1,-1)$ and must pass through the point $A=(1,-2,-1)$

\begin{align}
   (x,y,z)\circ(0,1,-1) &= A\circ (0,1,-1) \\
   y-z &= -1 \\
\end{align}

Note that both points $A$ and $B$ and none of the points on $L_x(s)$ satisfy the equation $y-z=-1$.