# How to define a line segment in math?

Tags: analytic-geometry

Can anyone tell me if I defined the blue line segment in the figure below correctly? Here is my definition of the blue line segment:

$L=\bigl\{ (x,y) \in  \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \,| \, x \in [1,2] \text{ and } y=x  \bigr\}$

[figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9JZk.jpg)

Comment: Technically, this is a *line segment*, not a line. But otherwise correct.

Comment: Does this answer your title question? [Defining a line](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2386459/defining-a-line)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews thx a lot. Yes you are right it is a line segment. I edit the question. Best Regards